# Why can't I set this member variable in this member function?

Tags: c++, function, class, variables, output

So in this function it isn't setting breakout to 6. When it prints I get "breakout" with no number following it.

```
void tokens::driver()
{
   //comment(getInput());
  // std::cout<< "driver working"<<std::endl;
  breakout=6;
  std::cout<< "breakout"<<breakout<< std::endl;
  integerConstant(breakout);
  //symbol(getInput());
  std::cout<< "breakout"<<breakout<< std::endl;
}
```

My h file is as such:

```
class tokens
{
  public:
  void driver();
  char breakout;

  private:
  char getInput();
  char integerConstant(char input);
  char symbol(char input);
  char whatWord(char input);
  char comment(char input);
  bool symbolMap(char input);
  bool keywordMap(std::string input);
};
```

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Because `6 != '6'`

Comment: @user657267, how does that matter?  The OP is using `cout`.

Comment: @BatCoder ... `operator<<` has an overload for [characters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

Comment: @BatCoder Probably because a `char` with the value `6` is a non-printable character (`ACK`) whereas `'6'` has the value of `54`. (when considering ASCII characters)

Comment: Thankyou everyone, dumb mistake lol. But that was interesting to ASCII values!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 breakout=6;
```

The above statement assigns the ascii value of `6` to `breakout` which is [ACK](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is non printable.

Answer (score 1):

Originally `breakout` is set to 6, which as a character encoding value is a non-printable ASCII character.

One possible effect of passing `char` value 6 to `cout`, is that nothing is displayed. A nice little trick to instead pass it as an integer, is to use the prefix `+` operator, like this: `+breakout`. Then you should see the value 6.

In `integerConstant` the single argument is passed by value. This makes a copy of the actual argument. Changes made to the copy are not reflected in the actual argument.

---

If you intended `breakout` to be the *character* “6”, then you should specify it enclosed in plain apostrophes, like this:

```
breakout = '6';
```

The ASCII value for the character ”6” is 48 + 6 = 54, so except on some old IBM mainframes (that use EBCDIC instead of ASCII), the above assignment is equivalent to

```
breakout = 54;
```

But it's more clear to write `'6'` than `54`.